# Searching for strings with hyperlinks in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, hyperlink, wildcards

In Outlook 2016 (for Windows) I can successfully find `(me@example.com)` using:

- non-wildcard search `(me@example.com)`
- wildcard search `\([a-z]@\@[a-z.]@.com\)`

However, both methods fail if the e-mail address is hyperlinked.

Is there a way to make the search ignore or include hyperlinks? A solution working for wildcard searches is preferable. I have seen [a suggestion](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other/findreplace-in-hyperlinks/0f78b0a1-d7d0-48c5-865a-a240d16aef8c?auth=1) that includes pressing `Alt+F9` to show field codes, but I didn't have success using that.

Comment: It's just as bad for any text that is a hyperlink. This is especially annoying in an Agile environment when I mention a Jira ID in an email. As a courtesy to my readers, I had been making the IDs hyperlinks, e.g. `<a href="https://myco.atlassian.net/browse/proj1-101">proj1-101</a>`. But then Outlook cannot find "proj1-101" in searches! I'm now trying to get in the habit of crafting my messages this way: `proj1-101 (<a href="https://myco.atlassian.net/browse/proj1-101">link</a>)`.